# \printbibliography needed for chapter/section bibliographies?

Tags: biblatex, lyx

I've created a LyX document with Biblatex (LyX 2.3.6.2, BasicTeX 2022, TexLive Utility, MacOS 12.6), set to produce a bibliography for every section. After activating section bibliographies, the bibliography at the end of the document goes away (as expected), and the references are re-numbered (i.e. now I have one ref labeled [1] per section).

But the document contains no section bibliographies. They are only included, if I add `\printbibliography` at the end of each section.

This is different behavior than I expected. Is that the intended way this should work?

Comment: Yes, it is the intended way.

Comment: @Guido Thank you!